# Problem in handling dual authentication in expect script with yes/no clause

Tags: linux, expect

I am new to expect programming. There is a need to create a script that handles single or double authentication with yes no clause as well. For example: if the user logs in to a system using spawn ssh, the user can be prompted for are you sure want to continue(yes/no)? or is asked to enter a password once or twice. The script should be dynamic enough to handle any of the three conditions.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set passw [lindex $argv 0];
spawn ssh user@ip
expect {
"(yes/no)?" {send "yes\r"
expect "assword: "
send "$passw\r"
expect {
"password: "{
send "$passw\r"
expect "<*>"
send "pwd\r"
expect "<*>"
}
"<*>" { send "pwd\r"
expect "<*>"
}}}
"*assword: " {
send "$passw\r"
expect {
"*assword: " {
send "$passw\r"
expect "<*>"
send "sys\r"
expect "<*>"
send "q\r"
}
"<*>" { send "sys\r"
expect "<*>"
send "q\r"}
}}}
```

The issue is the above scripts work fine for single password handling nodes. But fails in the case where the node requires dual authentication. Please let me know what wrong am I writing in my script.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The output for the script in case of dual authentication is -  spawn ssh user@ip

Comment: Proper indentation and formatting would make it a lot more readable...

Comment: Search the [tag:expect] tag for `exp_continue`

Answer (score 0):

Yes using exp_continue worked for me. My script is running as per the expectation.
This is how it looks like

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f
    set passw [lindex $argv 0];
    set timeout 120
    spawn ssh user@ip
 expect {
       "(yes/no)?" {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
        }
      "assword: " {
      send "$passw\r"
      exp_continue
      }
      "<*>" { send "pwd\r"
      expect "<*>"
      send "pwd\r"
      expect "<*>"
      send "q\r"
     }
  }
```